# PL/SQL GROUPING SETS and SUM

Tags: plsql

Would anybody know if this is possible at all. I have this table:

```
    +---------+--------+----------+---------------+
    | SOR_NUM | SOR_ID | SOR_COST | SOR_LINE_COST |
    +---------+--------+----------+---------------+
    |       7 |      1 |       10 |            35 |
    |       7 |      1 |       10 |            37 |
    |       7 |      1 |       10 |            39 |
    |       7 |      2 |       20 |            35 |
    |       7 |      2 |       20 |            32 |
    +---------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

I would like to get subtotals (with grouping sets maybe)like this:

```
+---------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| SOR_NUM |    SOR_ID     | SOR_COST | SOR_LINE_COST |
+---------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|       7 | 1             |       10 |            35 |
|       7 | 1             |       10 |            37 |
|       7 | 1             |       10 |            39 |
|       7 | Total SOR_ID  |       10 |           111 |
|       7 | 2             |       20 |            35 |
|       7 | 2             |       20 |            32 |
|       7 | Total SOR_ID  |       20 |            67 |
|       7 | Total SOR_NUM |       30 |           178 |
+---------+---------------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please show us your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You may look into `ROLLUP` and `GROUPING` functions of the [Oracle SQL functions for Aggregation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007434).

The query below gives the output you want, however some tweaking with `SOR_COST` takes place. I attribute this to the fact that your data is not sufficiently normalized.

```
select sub2.sor_num,
       case when sub2.sor_id is null then 'Total SOR_ID'
            when sub2.sor_cost is null then 'Total SOR_NUM'
            else to_char(sub2.sor_id) end sor_id,
       nvl(sub2.sor_cost, sub2.sum_sub1_one_sor_cost) sor_cost,
       nvl(sub2.sor_line_cost, sub2.sum_sub2_sum_sor_line_cost) sor_line_cost
  from (select case when (grouping(sub1.sor_num) = 0 and
                          grouping(sub1.sor_id) = 0 and
                          grouping(sub1.sor_cost) = 0 and
                          grouping(sub1.sor_line_cost) = 0) then 1
                    when (grouping(sub1.sor_num) = 0 and
                          grouping(sub1.sor_id) = 1 and
                          grouping(sub1.sor_cost) = 1 and
                          grouping(sub1.sor_line_cost) = 1) then 2
                    else 0 end show_row,
               max(sub1.sor_id) ord,
               sub1.sor_num,
               sub1.sor_id,
               sub1.sor_cost,
               sum(sub1.one_sor_cost) sum_sub1_one_sor_cost,
               sub1.sor_line_cost,
               sum(sub1.sum_sor_line_cost) sum_sub2_sum_sor_line_cost
          from (select grouping(x.sor_num) grp_1,
                       grouping(x.sor_id) grp_2,
                       grouping(x.sor_cost) grp_3,
                       grouping(x.sor_line_cost) grp_4,
                       x.sor_num,
                       x.sor_id,
                       x.sor_cost,
                       nvl2(x.sor_cost, null, min(x.sor_cost)) one_sor_cost,
                       sum(x.sor_line_cost) sor_line_cost,
                       nvl2(x.sor_line_cost, null, sum(x.sor_line_cost)) sum_sor_line_cost
                  from (select 7  sor_num, 1  sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 35 sor_line_cost from dual union all
                        select 7  sor_num, 1  sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 37 sor_line_cost from dual union all
                        select 7  sor_num, 1  sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 39 sor_line_cost from dual union all
                        select 7  sor_num, 2  sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 35 sor_line_cost from dual union all
                        select 7  sor_num, 2  sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 32 sor_line_cost from dual) x
                 group by x.sor_num,
                          x.sor_id,
                          rollup(x.sor_cost, x.sor_line_cost)) sub1
         where ((sub1.grp_3 = 1 and sub1.grp_2 = 0 and sub1.grp_1 = 0) or
               (sub1.grp_1 = 0 and sub1.grp_2 = 0 and sub1.grp_3 = 0 and
               sub1.grp_4 = 0))
         group by rollup(sub1.sor_num,
                         sub1.sor_id,
                         sub1.sor_cost,
                         sub1.sor_line_cost)) sub2
 where sub2.show_row > 0
 order by sub2.sor_num, sub2.show_row, sub2.ord, sub2.sor_cost nulls last
```

Comment: Hmm, this query doesn't work in case several SOR_ID have same SOR_COST example: (select 7 sor_num, 1 sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 35 sor_line_cost from dual union all select 7 sor_num, 1 sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 37 sor_line_cost from dual union all select 7 sor_num, 1 sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 39 sor_line_cost from dual union all select 7 sor_num, 2 sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 35 sor_line_cost from dual union all select 7 sor_num, 2 sor_id, 22 sor_cost, 32 sor_line_cost from dual). By the way this table is result of several joins

Comment: I've updated the code to deal with this. However, I think there should be a nicer way to achieve the same.

Comment: Now this query is OK!